# What should input for the app domain for sender whitelist in Chromecast extension developer options?

Tags: chromecast

I will summarize the working flow of `chrome-cast` with a few questions.

Please help confirm it is correct.

A. Sender APP first sends the `APPID` to `Chrome-cast Device`, 
B. Then the Device looks for the `receiver.html` according to `APPID` and `white listed URL mapping`.
C. The Device loads the `receiver.html` and establishes a connection channel with Sender APP.

Question for A:  For chrome extension sender app, it is said that it needs to input the app domain into `Chrome-cast extension` for `white list sender`.

What should input be for the app domain for a sender html in sample `https://github.com/googlecast/cast-chrome-sender-helloworld`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps are conceptually close to what happens. For your main question, it seems like you are doing a chrome sender. As such, you need to run your sender application on a web server, whether a local one inside your network or outside, accessible globally. If it is inside your local network, you need to use ip address; if outside, you can use ip address or name. You only need to whitelist the domain in the extension, for example if you are running your sender app locally at `http://192.168.1.100/mypath/index.html`, you would need to whitelist `192.168.1.100`. If you are hosting it outside using a domain name, say `http://acme.com/path/index.html`, just whitelist `acme.com` with the extension.

Comment: Thanks alot for the instructions.